# how to check the charset and collation of mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, charset

how to check the charset and collation of mysql database? or what command to the charset and collation of mysql database?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE database-name
```

And for seeing the collation of tables inside,

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table-name
```